# Fibonnaci recurring value is not returning

Tags: java

This Fibonnaci program result is not printing the result.

```
public  int fibo(int n) {
    if(n <=1)
      return 1;
   else
      return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the number upto fibo needs");
    int number=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("1st stage");
    Fibonnaci obj=new Fibonnaci();
    obj.fibo(number);
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of the fibo method, you just throw it away. It won't print it magically!

Comment: use system.out.printlin(obj.fibo(number));

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the result of

```
obj.fibo(number)
```

Try

```
System.out.println(obj.fibo(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

fibo() method written is wrong. It should be implemented in the following way:

```
public int fibo(int n) {

if (n == 1)
    return 1;
else if (n == 0)
    return 0;
else
    return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
}
```

Generally F(0)=0, F(1)=1. But the code you are using, implies F(0)=F(1)=1, thus giving wrong result. Above code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mfsi_sitamj said, your main problem is that your stop conditions are false (i. e. the cases where n=0 and n =0).

Fibonnaci is a cool occasion to speak about memoisation.

> F(0) = 0 
>   F(1) = 1 
>   F(2) = F(1) + F(0)  (Which are constants) 
>   F(3) = F(2) + F(1) (One is calculated, the other is constant) 
>   F(4) = F(3) + F(2) (Both are calculated, but F(2) is Recalculated twice : to get F(3) and F(2).

Quickly everything get slow because there is a lot of recalculation.

The solution is to keep in memory the past results. 
The best data structure to store an association between two values is a map.
So for each result `F(n)=x`, I store in my map an new entry set (n, x) and check if it exists before recalculating it uselessly.

Here is my quick proposition. Note that the max you can test is `Fibo(46)` because a higher number will give a `double` result.

Try it and see the difference of execution time ;-). You can change the call to `fibo_memoisation(number, false)` to `fibo_memoisation(number, true)` to see what is calculated and stored value is used.

```
public class Fibonnaci {


    // Classic way corrected.
    public int fibo(int n) {

        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
        }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> memoisation_table = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();


    public int fibo_memoisation(int n, boolean verbose) {

        int fibo_n_minus_one, fibo_n_minus_two;

        if(n == 0) return 0;
        if(n == 1) return 1;


        if(memoisation_table.containsKey(n-1)) 
        {
            fibo_n_minus_one = memoisation_table.get(n-1);
            if(verbose)System.out.println("fibo("+ (n-1) +")=" + fibo_n_minus_one + " Is known (-1)");
        }
        else
        {
            fibo_n_minus_one = fibo_memoisation(n-1, verbose);
            memoisation_table.put(n-1, fibo_n_minus_one);
            if(verbose)System.out.println("fibo("+ (n-1) +")=" + fibo_n_minus_one + " was calculated (-1)");
        }

        if(memoisation_table.containsKey(n-2)) 
        {
            fibo_n_minus_two = memoisation_table.get(n-2);
            if(verbose)System.out.println("fibo("+ (n-2) +")=" + fibo_n_minus_two + " Is known (-2)");
        }
        else
        {
            fibo_n_minus_two = fibo_memoisation(n-2, verbose);
            memoisation_table.put(n-2, fibo_n_minus_two);
            if(verbose)System.out.println("fibo("+ (n-2) +")=" + fibo_n_minus_two + " was calculated (-2)");
        }



        int res = fibo_n_minus_one + fibo_n_minus_two;
        memoisation_table.put(n, res);
        return res;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number upto fibo needs");
        int number=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("1st stage");

        Fibonnaci obj=new Fibonnaci();


        // Memoisation way
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        int res = obj.fibo_memoisation(number, false);
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long time_memoisation = (long) ((now - before) / 1000.0);
        System.out.println("fibo_memoisation("+number+") = " +res + " took " +  time_memoisation + "ms to compute");

        // Handy result after memoisation!
        System.out.println("Computed fibonnaci table : ");
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> i : obj.memoisation_table.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Fibo("+i.getKey()+") = " + i.getValue());
        }


        // Classic way
        System.out.println("classic way :");
        before = System.nanoTime();
        res = obj.fibo(number);
         now = System.nanoTime();
         long time = (long) ((now - before) / 1000.0);
        System.out.println("fibo("+number+") = " +res + " took " +  time + "ms to compute ("  + time/time_memoisation + " times slower)");
    }
}
```